# Codeigniter pagination is not passing the correct link value in url

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

I have created a pagination in codeigniter, In that I have totally 13 records and i want to display 5 records in each page. When i click on the pagination link number 2,It should pass value 2 in url and it show the next 5 records but I am getting value 5 in url instead of 2.

My controller code:

```
 public function activities($page_num = 1){
     $config =array();
     $config['base_url'] = base_url().'admin/skills/activities';
     $config['per_page'] = 5;
     $config['total_rows'] = $this->skill_model->all_activities(0,'',''); // I will get the total count from my model

     if(empty($page_num))
         $page_num = 1;

   $limit_end = ($page_num-1) * $config['per_page']; //end limit
   $limit_start = $config['per_page'];    // start limit
   $this->pagination->first_url = $config['base_url'].'/1';
   $this->pagination->initialize($config); 
   $data['activity_list'] = $this->skill_model->all_activities(1,$limit_start,$limit_end);
}
```

This is my view code:

```
<?php echo '<div class="pagination" style="float:right;">'.$this->pagination->create_links().'</div>'; ?>
```

My Model part:

```
function all_activities($flag,$limit_start,$limit_end){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('skills_activities');
    //echo $limit_start." ".$limit_end; 
    if($flag == 1 ){
        $this->db->limit($limit_start, $limit_end);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    } else {
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->num_rows();
    }
}
```

When i click on pagination link I am getting the following url:

```
  http://192.168.1.97/projects/homecare/admin/skills/activities/5
```

but I should get:

```
  http://192.168.1.97/projects/homecare/admin/skills/activities/2
```

I don't know where i have done a mistake.
can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $limit_end = ($page_num-1) * $config['per_page']; // $limit_end = (1-1) * 5 so result will be 0

Comment: @Rana: Yeah,first time it is 0 so i will get limit as 0,5.. Next time page_num will be 2,so (2-1)*5 =5, I will get limit as 5,5 for next 5 record.

Comment: so $this->skill_model->all_activities(1,$limit_start,$limit_end); will be $this->skill_model->all_activities(1,5,0); will return 0 result

Comment: paste your **all_activities()** function

Comment: @Rana: I have pasted.. see the above code..

Comment: @Rana: I am able to retrieve first five record.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67316/discussion-between-malar-and-rana-soyab).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$config['use_page_numbers'] = true;
```

This will produce page number in the url instead of record number. By default its false.

So you controller will look like this

```
public function activities($page_num = 1)
{
  $config =array();
  $config['base_url'] = base_url().'admin/skills/activities';
  $config['per_page'] = 5;
  $config['use_page_numbers'] = true;//you missed this line
  $config['total_rows'] = $this->skill_model->all_activities(0,'',''); // I will get   the total count from my model
  if(empty($page_num)) $page_num = 1;
  $limit_end = ($page_num-1) * $config['per_page']; //end limit
  $limit_start = $config['per_page'];    // start limit
  $this->pagination->first_url = $config['base_url'].'/1';
  $this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

Comment: I have not found any such kind of $config['use_page_numbers'] in my configuration file.

Comment: You missed this config. Just add the line bellow `$config['per_page'] = 5;` at your controller

Comment: See my code properly.. I have given this $config['per_page'] = 5;

Comment: Check my modified answer.